# Check if the case owner is a user or queue before changing status

Tags: formula, validation-rule, validation

I want to write a validation rule that the case owner should only be a user and not the queue before changing the case status to 'Assigned'. I wrote the following formula but it is not working:

```
AND( 
ISPICKVAL( Status__c , "Assigned") ,
 BEGINS( OwnerId , "005") )
```

Comment: Is status a picklist field?

Comment: yes it is a picklist field

Comment: Does validation need to fire is owner is changed to queue when it is in Assigned status?

Answer (score 0):

Validation works on an is true basis to kick an error up so what you want is to start an error if the owner ID doesn't start with "005" (User prefix)

```
AND( 
    ISPICKVAL( Status__c , "Assigned") ,
    NOT( BEGINS( OwnerId , "005") )
)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. what should I do if I want to add another status value to the validation rule? for example, the owner should be a user when the status is changed to either Assigned or Closed? –

Comment: The only question is which has more statuses? it might be easier to do

    NOT( ISPICKVAL( Status__c , "To Be Assigned") )
rather than listing every one it could be as if you add extra statuses it will not trigger against the new statuses until you add them like below
    OR(ISPICKVAL(Status__c,"Assigned"),ISPICKVAL(Status__c,"Closed"))

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your validation rule is as Status__c field is Picklist Value field you have to use `ISPICKVAL()` or `TEXT()` to convert into text and then campare with value 'Assigned'.

The other issue is it should not be Queue means you have to use formula such that it should not start with '00G'

So the validation will be as below.

```
AND( ISPICKVAL(Status__c,"Assigned") , BEGINS( OwnerId , "00G") )
```

The above validation rule works if we are trying to update the owner to Queue after changing the status to 'Working' as well and any field is updated.

If you want to work the validation only when status is changed to Assigned and owner is Queue you have to use as below

```
AND(NOT(ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status__c),"Assigned")), ISPICKVAL(Status__c,"Assigned") , BEGINS( OwnerId , "00G") )
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. what should I do if I want to add another status value to the validation rule? for example, the owner should be a user when the status is changed to either Assigned or Closed?

Comment: You have to use `OR(ISPICKVAL(Status__c,"Assigned"),ISPICKVAL(Status__c,"Closed"))` in place of `ISPICKVAL(Status__c,"Assigned")`